# doctrine 2 -correct way of working with associated objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

what is the correct way of persisting associated objects?

example

```
class User{
  /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", cascade={"persist", "remove"}) */
  private $profile;
}
```

if i change a property in the profile object like this $user->profile->setText('text');

and then do 
$em->persist($user) nothing happens. i tried persisting also the profile, setting the changed profile back to the user object, persisting both, but the profile record never gets updated.

how is this done?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$user = new mjOfficeBase_modelos_Usuario; 
$user->setNombre('Mr.Pepito'); 
$em->persist($user); 
$em->flush();
```

Comment: i dont mean this, this is clear to me. i need to change of an associated object and then persist the changes

Comment: Have you try `$em->persist($user->profile); $em->flush(); ` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = // get the user
$profile = $user->getProfile();
$profile->setText('text');
$em->persist($profile);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

Does that work ?